# What are the differences among ChromeOptions, capabilities and preferences in Chromedriver?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

What are the differences among the three choices in their usages and functions? Are there lists for their arguments?

Comment: You are capable of constructing a well thought out question but you prefer not to. I assume Chromedriver follows the same verb usages. Please read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

ChromeOptions are specific to Chromedriver.  (you can pass prefs into the ChromeDriver constructor...)  Capabilities are for Selenium WebDriver. (so more global... things like setting paths to driver, browser etc...)